# We have a chat room now!

Tags: discussion, chat

I didn't realize it before, but it seems that we have a chat-room dedicated to us....so an obvious question is....

What should we talk about in the chat room? What is appropriate for that?

Comment: I was kind of hoping no-one would notice that ...

Comment: With the blatantly prominent "chat" label on the top, it's a miracle no one noticed it any sooner (or people didn't care all that much about it).

Answer (score 6):

The main topic in [the main chat room for TeX.SX](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) is the same as the site's topic but other things are discussed to (such as sports and cats). Often there are discussion about TeX problems and things happening on the site. Just drop by the , and have a look. You do not have to say anything.

Also note that you can make your own chat rooms, e.g. for other topics or private chats, and you can read transcripts of old chat discussions. See also [What is happening in Chat rooms?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/what-is-happening-in-chat-rooms)

Comment: We were just briefly discussing llamas in chat a while ago.  Great community.  Its always a pleasure to pop into chat.

Comment: We talk (or quarrel) about music, for example. :)